# Highlighting two rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have code to input information and then compare that information to a table. I want to highlight the new row being created and the one we are comparing the new row to. Here is my code

```
Sub findData()
    Dim workflow As String
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        workflow = .Range("C5").Value
        servergri = .Range("C9").Value
        gridf = .Range("C9").Value
        StartTime = .Range("c11").Value
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet3")
        finalrow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 5 To finalrow
            If .Cells(i, 3) = workflow And (.Cells(i, 4) = servergri Or .Cells(i, 5) = gridf) Then

                .Rows(i).Insert
                'Add new information to the new row.
                'The new row number is still = i

                .Cells(i, 3) = workflow
                .Cells(i, 4) = servergri
                .Cells(i, 6) = StartTime


                'If you only want to add one row then your should exit the loop
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Call Worksheet_SelectionChange
End Sub

Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange()
    Dim Target As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Clear the color of all the cells
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    ' Highlight the active cell
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You never set `Target` to be anything other than declaring it as a `Range` in the `SelectionChange` event...

Comment: So how do I assign it to the new and comparing row? @Dave

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`

Comment: This seems like it will be better and more responsive with conditional formatting formulas instead of VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add

```
.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
.Cells(i, 3).Resize(2, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
```

after

```
.Cells(i, 6) = StartTime
```